# Error: Chrome - not allowed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browser-sync

Everything works fine with BrowserSync so far but I have a silly problem with loading the jpg file. Error appears in Chrome console "not allowed to load local resource" after gulp watch automatically starts the page and everything works fine except I cannot see my background picture on the page. Image is located in the folder with my project. I don't have such a problem when I am opening the page(double click index.html) without gulp watch task.

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");

var watch = require("gulp-watch");
postcss = require("gulp-postcss");
autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
cssvars = require("postcss-simple-vars");
nested = require("postcss-nested");
cssImport = require("postcss-import");
browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

gulp.task('default', function() {
    console.log("yeeey!");
});

gulp.task("html", function() {
    console.log("html task");
});

gulp.task("styles", function() {
    return gulp.src("./app/assets/styles/styles.css")
        .pipe(postcss([cssImport, cssvars, nested, autoprefixer]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./app/temp/styles"));
});

gulp.task("watch", function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "app"
        }
    });

    watch("./app/index.html", function() {
        gulp.start("html");
    });
    watch("./app/assets/styles/**/*.css", function() {
        gulp.start("styles");
    });
});
```

And that is the way I've navigated to the picture in index.html

```
<img src="C:/Users/aa/Desktop/Web-dev-course/Projects/travel-site/app/assets/images/Wietnam/v111.jpg">
```

Thanks for any help!

Ann

Comment: Do you have the file in the `./app` folder, i mean the same folder as index.html => `./app/index.html`? how do you link the jpg file, is it this way `background-image: url("/img.jpg");`? Ideally add the code where you link the file to you question so others can see.

Comment: Thanks for response, I've just added the code you mantioned. I've navigated from disk C.. I know something is wrong with that and Chrome cannot load files from local folder. I've tried to navigate like this "./images/Wietnam/v111.jpg", but still nothing.

Comment: Try `/assets/images/Wietnam/v111.jpg`.

Comment: Yes, it works in that way, but before that I had to move my gulp folder out of an app folder.. (both are now in the main project folder like: /project/app and /project/gulp) connect dots in "pipe" because of gulp watch error.. Maybe it was because in the course they use older versions of tools. Thank you anyway, it makes that I really had to figure it out on my own too ;)